# Masking `nan` on tensorflow efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, masking

Suppose I want to run a simple deep-learning classification model. Here is a data example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = pd.DataFrame({
    'v1': [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 6],
    'v2': [0.3119080, 0.9352281, 0.2509079, 0.8880956, -1.1892642, np.nan],
    'v3': [-1.36932765, np.nan, 0.02033295, 0.35838342, -1.11678819, 1.86502911],
})
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

And here is an illustrative model (not sure if it is going to work, just an example):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape = (3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(input)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)
model.compile(optimizer = "Adam", loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
model.fit(X, y)
```

Now, my problem: If I drop the NaNs, I will have only three observations. Is there a way to mask each case with NaN so that the Neural Net still uses valid observations from the other variables?

Things I don't want (otherwise, it would make this Q very obvious): 1) change with means. 2) Change for any other value that does not make sense for the problem.

I was thinking of zeroing the variable (I believe this is what dropout layers do, right?), but am unsure if this is ok (and violates the thing 2 above).

Thanks!